# Does quantifier dependence involve putting ∃ before ∀ (or vice versa)?

Tags: symbolic-logic, quantification

I don't know why I'm having such trouble getting the gist of the SEP article on [independence-friendly logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-if/#IntQuaDep), but I am. I also remain perplexed about a comment I received on the MathOverflow about the order of the "for some" vs. the "for all" quantifier. But most importantly: "for all *A*, there exists some *B*..." is ambiguous between (1) a reading where there is one and the same *B* for all the *A*, and (2) a reading where there is a separate *B* for each *A*. Is that difference tracked by the order of the quantifiers?

**Is that what quantifier dependence amounts to?** I'm having trouble seeing what is the matter, here, otherwise. I can appreciate, as a witless outsider, that something is the matter in this case, but whether all of the above issues coincide, I don't know.

Comment: Compare "for every integer there is a greater one" which is true, with "there is an integer that is great that every integer" that is false. In the first case the choice of the element existentially quantified depends on the value of the element instantiating the universal quantifier.

Comment: "Forall A there exists a B" means that for each A there is a B. It doesn't say whether two A's have the same B or not. If you wanted specify that either that (1) all the A's have the same B or that (2) each A is associated with a unique B, you'd need extra machinery.

Comment: I see what you mean about that article. It's a little hard to follow. However, I think I got the point by focusing on the Skolem normal form.

Comment: A simpler example of dependence: "for every human there is a father".

Comment: Not exactly. The "dependence" here refers to quantifiers creating dependencies between different variables. So  ∀x∃y creates a dependence (as in the epsilon-delta definition of continuity) but ∃x∀y does not (as in uniform continuity). You can see it in Skolemization, in the first case you need a function y=f(x) to remove the quantifiers, while in the second you can just replace x with a constant. I think [Sandu's Dependence and Independence of Quantifiers in Logic](https://compass.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1747-9991.2012.00511.x) is better at explaining the gist  than SEP.

Comment: Order of finite quantifiers in Skolem forms matters in the sense of dependency scope of even existential quantifier (W Hodges's slash logic expresses independence from even previous existential quantifier bounded variables), along with the fact that semantic quantifers/variables relations can only be syntactically expressed via quantifiers, wherefore IF logic is much more expressive than classic FOL by adding one more independence syntactic sugar but with semantic incompleteness and could outperform set theory as math foundation and offer more powerful *de re* semantics of natural languages...